# PHP date_format not displaying full textual month as instructed

Tags: php

It appears I'm incorrectly using the date_format method. I'm able to echo my desired month numerically but unable to echo the full text "January" or "February" for example. Could someone please point me in the right direction? Thank you in advance.

```
<?php    
    $thismonth=date("m");
    $nextmonth=date("m")+1;
    echo date_format($thismonth, "F");
    echo date_format($nextmonth, "F");
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo date('F d, Y'); ->> today
echo date('F d, Y', strtotime('+1 month')); ->> next month
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Following

```
$current_month   = date('F');
$next_month      = date('F', strtotime('+1 month'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The date function returns you a number, not a unix timestamp, and date_format except a unix timestamp.

You need something like this:

```
<?php    
    $thismonth = time();
    $nextmonth = strtotime('+1 month');
    echo date_format($thismonth, "F");
    echo date_format($nextmonth, "F");
?>
```